# calculate the correct space between dots on a dashed circle, to have a perfect alignment

Tags: circles

I want to draw a dashed circle, with a diameter D, and X dots composing the circle, like on this image:
[dashed circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsH3B.png)

How can I define the exact space I should have between the different dots, to avoid the misalignment you can see on the right of the circle?
I think that an equation involving D, X, and Pi should work, but I do not find the solution...

Many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "space between dots"? Their distance? The angle they form with the center? Something else?

Comment: @Jeremy You need to give more details about how you are currently trying to determine the space, or how you are drawing the misaligned version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want $X$ dots the angle between two  successive dots is $\alpha=2\pi/X$ and the distance between them, measured as an arc on the circle, is $D \alpha/2$.

All this come form the fact that $c=2 \pi r$.

Answer (score 0):

You want the dots to be at the ends of radii (length $R=D/2$) at angles $360/X$ degrees. The coordinates will be 
$$
\left(R\cos\left(j \frac{360}{X}\right), R\sin\left(j \frac{360}{X}\right)\right)
$$
for $j = 0, 1, \ldots , X-1$.